# How to handle errors of Kafka from Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am reading messages from a Kafka topic in Scala in the following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

val topicMessagesMap = topicMessages.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads)).toMap

val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMessagesMap).map(_._2)
```

I wonder what is the right way to handle possible connection failing, especially considering that my Spark Streaming job will be running during a long time and surely there will be some connection issues during this period. 
I want that the Streaming job would not stop in case of the connection issue, but **it should rather try to reconnect automatically and read all the messages that it did not process before the connection failing**.

I assume that I should properly setup `auto.offset.reset`, `auto.commit.interval.ms`, etc., but a detailed guidance for putting proper settings would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the abstraction provided by Spark for Kafka, errors are handled for you such that you need not worry about them, unless your Kafka cluster has failed and you can no longer process messages, in which case will make the streaming application eventually terminate.

For example, [you can read the part of the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/ReliableKafkaReceiver.scala#L261) that actually handles Kafka messages (this is only relevant for the receiver based approach):

```
/** Class to handle received Kafka message. */
private final class MessageHandler(stream: KafkaStream[K, V]) extends Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      while (!isStopped) {
        try {
          val streamIterator = stream.iterator()
          while (streamIterator.hasNext) {
            storeMessageAndMetadata(streamIterator.next)
          }
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
            reportError("Error handling message", e)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but according to my tests, when zookeeper or kafka is off, then my code stops. However I would like that it waits and checks again the kafka queue in, let's say, 10 minutes and so on. Then I also want to not loose the messages sent. How can I control it with offset? Should I set it as `earliest` or should I control it manually?

Comment: @duckertito That isn't something you can configure.

Comment: I thought it's possible to capture such cases. But it's very strange actually. In case of using Spark Streaming + Kafka, it means that there is an opened connection. If the Spark Streaming job is a long running (for instance X months till some maintenance), then surely there will be situations with connection failing. So, what is normally done in such cases then? How to prevent such situations? Should I inspect the Kafka every day or how to automate it?